# Excel Macro to Locate Duplicate Values of a Column and Copy Adjacent Cells

Tags: vba, excel

I need an Excel Macro that loops through a column (in my case Column E) and finds duplicates. Once it has located a duplicate, it should copy the leftmost 2 cells of the first duplicate row and paste it into the second duplicate row.

Here is a concrete example of what I am talking about:

This is the worksheet before the macro:

```
     A      B      C      D      E
1    A11    B11    C11    D11    Text1
2    A22    B22    C22    D22    Text2
3    A33    B33    C33    D33    Text3
4
5
6
7                                Text3
8                                Text2
```

It should detect that there are duplicates in column E and copy leftmost 2 cells of the first iteration of the duplicate rows and paste them into the second iteration. Namely it should copy A33 and B33 from Text3's row and paste it into the latter Text3's row. Same with Text2. Thus the worksheet should show this after the macro has run:

```
     A      B      C      D      E
1    A11    B11    C11    D11    Text1
2    A22    B22    C22    D22    Text2
3    A33    B33    C33    D33    Text3
4
5
6
7    A33    B33                  Text3
8    A22    B22                  Text2
```

Comment: THere's literally 1000 questions just like this. Please search for similar questions, and come back when you have a specific, code-related question other than "Please write my code for me".

Comment: @David Zemens I have spent the last hour looking through past stackoverflow questions and while there are some similar questions, I have had some trouble adapting them to my issue. I don't really have much experience with Excel Macros or VBA at all...

Comment: Please update your question to include what you are currently attempting (including code) and describe where it is failing or how it is not working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub main()
Dim hold As New Collection
For Each celli In Columns(5).Cells
On Error GoTo raa
If Not celli.Value = Empty Then
hold.Add Item:=celli.Row, key:="" & celli.Value
End If
Next celli
On Error Resume Next
raa:
Range("a1:b1").Offset(celli.Row - 1, 0).Value = Range("a1:b1").Offset(hold(celli.Value) - 1, 0).Value
Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. This works perfectly. I also figured out what was going wrong with my code. Apparently my offsets were not working and I was trying to reference a string as a range.